# Insert new row into SQL DB column using a record's unique ID (C#)

Tags: c#, sql

I am wondering how I can insert multiple rows into a column in C# with a specified record ID number.

For example, I have a notes column. I don't want to update the note already there, but I want to add new notes to a specific record in the DB. (which is done by specifying a record's unique ID number).

How can I go about doing this?

*Small Diagram*

Now
Patient ID: 1
Patient Note: *a note*

What I'd like to do:
Patient ID: 1
Patient Note: *a note*
Patient Note: *another note* (in a new row) but assigned to the same patient.

Please note that I am not having trouble specifying which record the note is going to be 'attached to', via giving the DB the ID number, it is the adding of multiple notes (in the consultationNotes column) for a patient that I am concerned about (*just in case* it is unclear from the initial explanation).

Comment: Dont set ID as primary key , that would do the job for you!or create another table with the relationship patientid and add several notes for particular id

Comment: Create a new table for the note. It should have at least two columns: PatientId and Note. You can enter as many notes as you want for any patient. Than you can (should) create relationship between the two tables and link Patient and Note tables via PatientId. Look up one to many relationships for more details.

Comment: Hi MirekE, I'll implement your solution. Thanks! Does the "one to many" relationship allow me to add as many notes as I want per patient? Or, is there something else I must do? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many as you like (as long as there is enough free space on the disks)!